# How do I move the camera in 2D LWJGL openGL?

Tags: opengl, java, camera, lwjgl

I am making a top-down rpg game with the LWJGL but I can't figure out how to make the camera follow the player. I've tryed using GLU.gluLookAt() but it seems to be designed for 3D and when I try it with my game everything currently on the screen disappears. I have no idea where the camera gets moved to. Please explain simply how to use GLU.gluLookAt() or a better alternative to move the camera.

```
public class Camera {

    public float x = 0;
    public float y = 0;

    public void moveCamera(float toX, float toY){
    GLU.gluLookAt(x+toX, y+toY, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three arguments of gluLookAt are position of your camera. The next three is the point the camera is looking at. So you have to move *looking at point* as well as the position of camera.

```
GLU.gluLookAt(x+toX, y+toY, z, x+toX, y+toY, 0.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
```

Don't forget to move away camera on z axis (but I'm not sure if it will be problem).

Another way is to make translation (glTranslatef) before you draw your game.

Comment: Sorry for such a simple question but what should the value of z variable be? The game's 2D so I assumed there was no z axis.

Comment: You are _holding_ your camera in 3D space. Your game is fake 2D because you are using only x and y (z=0). I am not sure but it could be a problem if your camera is at the same value of z. Just check.

Comment: Keep in mind that glTranslate is fixed function and has been deprecated in modern OpenGL.